# Convert Big Planet Tracks SQLite to mbtiles for OSMdroid

Tags: android, sqlite, osmdroid, mbtiles

I am looking a way to convert Big Planet Tracks SQLite to mbtiles.  What is the difference?  GDAL offers way to convert Geotiff to mbtiles in commandline.  Big Planet Tracks SQLite so far I know is only supported by Mobile_Atlas_Creator_1.8_SQLite.zip (http://android-map.blogspot.com/2010/11/mobile-atlas-creator-18.html).  Can I use Mobile Atlas Creator on command line to generate .mbtiles files instead of .sqlite files?

Answer (score 1):

> I am looking a way to convert Big Planet Tracks SQLite to mbtiles. What is the difference?

More than likely, the table structure is different.

MBTiles >> https://github.com/mapbox/mbtiles-spec/blob/master/1.2/spec.md

```
CREATE TABLE tiles (zoom_level integer, tile_column integer, tile_row integer, tile_data blob);
```

Big Tracks >> https://code.google.com/p/big-planet-tracks/source/browse/BigPlanetTracks/src/tyt/android/bigplanettracks/maps/storage/SQLLocalStorage.java

```
CREATE TABLE tiles (x int, y int, z int, s int, image blob, PRIMARY KEY (x,y,z,s))";
```

So their similar, as most tile database structures are. It looks possible to convert from one to the other format (although it's not clear what the column "s" is for in Big Tracks.

> Can I use Mobile Atlas Creator on command line to generate .mbtiles files instead of .sqlite files?

I don't know about from the command line, but Mobac definitely supports creating mbtiles.

Comment: no problem. feel free to mark as helpful or correct...or not

Comment: if you can find out what the "S" column, I can probably write in native support for it in osmdroid

Comment: after running a few tests with mobac, it looks like there's more than just a table schema difference. The zoom numbers stored in big tracks don't line up with osm's slippy map format.

Comment: the zoom numbers seem to be inverted. The standard slippy tiles use increasing zoom numbers for zooming in, while the big tracks format's maximum zoom value is 0.

Comment: From my tests it seems as if the minimum zoom value is 17. So to get the correct tile you must request (y,x,17-z),